# After authenticating website read the website is functional or not using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me with authenticating website with system@abc.com and to check website is functional or not? And also website has a search box, how to test using C# code that search box is functional?

Comment: On business site we have search box to search group/people, how to find out that search box is functional using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for testing if the website is functional :

```
        var url = "https://www.google.com/";
        WebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        if(res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //Website is functional
        }
```

Comment: It works for checking the site. Can you let me know how i can know that my search box is working which is present in the site.

Comment: If you have access to the website, try searching for something inside it from the browser, then copy the URL and replace it in the variable url in the C# code, and try if this works.